# Excel match function rreturns N/A without the reson

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good afternoon,

I have got a problem with my match function.

I am using the code, which should indicate the proper of the active cell.

```
     =(MATCH(A2,Tracker!A2:A3999))+1
```

But it only works to the A9 cell.

If I put new records underneath, it shows #N/A without the reason.

[image]

Could anyone help me to solve it?

If I drag it down to 9th cell then it starts working. What can be behind it? Under the OR1001 record, which is placed on A9 cell I should have the 9 value instead of #N/A

Comment: use `0` as the third criterion.  `=(MATCH(A2,Tracker!A2:A3999,0))+1`

Comment: It looks like it works. Thank you!